# Как сделать Многопользовательскую игру?

Tags: delphi, разработка-игр

Я сделал игру змейка и хочу попробовать сделать её на нескольких человек
Все части змейки храняться в массиве с типом

Код:

```
TPos = record
x, y: smallint;
end;
```

Каким образом можно сделать передачу координат между сервером и клиентом?
или может каким-то другим образом зделать?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на форму кинь клиен_сокет и сервер_сокет.

запускаешь  сервер. потом к нему подключаешь клиентов и передаешь данные на сервер, а сервер потом передает всем остальным данные.

например:

- client[0]->server: hello
- server->client[0]: hi
- client[0]->server: x=23,y=54
- server->client[0]: client_0*x=23,y=54
- server->client[1]: client_0*x=23,y=54
- server->client[2]: client_0*x=23,y=54

Comment: а есть какой нибудь пример с какой библиотекой лучше делать?

Comment: возможно ли передать массив с типом TPos ?

Comment: я работал немного с ICS. 
public
position:TPos 
procedure
begin
with position do
send(inttostr(x)+' '+inttostr(y));

как то так))